# What are some ways to track opened windows in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, selenium

Just wanted to get some ideas on how you guys track opened windows with Selenium. The UI test below just tests 2 windows but really there are about 4 windows I need to track that can be open simultaneously.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Multiple_windows_dictionary_tracker_test()
{
    //arrange
    _driver.Url = "http://localhost:58301/TestingMultiWindows.aspx";
    //Get something on page to make sure page loaded.
    IWebElement link = GetElement(By.Id("HyperLink1"));
    string windowOneTitle = "Window One";
    string windowTwoTitle = "Hello World";            
    //Track opened windows in dictionary
    Dictionary<string, string> openedWindows = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    openedWindows.Add(windowOneTitle, _driver.WindowHandles[0]);
    Inject_jQuery(string.Format("document.title = '{0}';", windowOneTitle), true);
    _wait.Until(x => _driver.Title == windowOneTitle);
    //act
    string secondWinKey = OpenNewWindow(windowTwoTitle, "HyperLink1", true);
    openedWindows.Add(windowTwoTitle, secondWinKey);
    //assert
    _wait.Until(x => _driver.Title == windowTwoTitle);
    _driver.SwitchTo().Window(openedWindows[windowOneTitle]);
    _wait.Until(x => _driver.Title == windowOneTitle);
}
```

Comment: If title won't be changed, use dictionary as your example. If title keep changing, create unique id then use the id as key in dictionary.

Comment: list of all your windows : var windowsList = driver.WindowHandles.ToList();